# Late timer label display while page loading using update panel

Tags: c#, asp.net, timer

I have used C# timer with updatepanel in my webpage, everything is working well except during the page loads my timer label displays after 3 seconds ie: for 3:00 mins the timer displays as 2:57 secs .

So how could it be resolved. Thanks in advance....

My aspx code is:

```
<div>
    <asp:ScriptManager ID= "SM1" runat="server">
    </asp:ScriptManager>
    <asp:Timer ID="timer1" runat="server" Interval="1000" OnTick="timer1_tick">
    </asp:Timer>
</div>
<div>
    <asp:UpdatePanel id="updPnl" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="lblTimer" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" Font-Names="Arial" Font-Size="X-Large" ForeColor="#6600CC"></asp:Label>&nbsp;&nbsp;
        </ContentTemplate>
        <Triggers>
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="timer1" EventName ="tick" />
        </Triggers>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
</div>
```

My asp.cs code is:

```
if (0 > DateTime.Compare(DateTime.Now, DateTime.Parse(Session["timeout"].ToString())))
{
    string seconds = ((Int32)DateTime.Parse(Session["timeout"].ToString()).Subtract(DateTime.Now).Seconds).ToString();
    if (Convert.ToInt32(seconds) < 10)
    {
        lblTimer.Text = string.Format("Time Left: 00:0{00}:0{01}", ((Int32)DateTime.Parse(Session["timeout"].ToString()).Subtract(DateTime.Now).TotalMinutes).ToString(),
            ((Int32)DateTime.Parse(Session["timeout"].ToString()).Subtract(DateTime.Now).Seconds).ToString());
    }
    else
    {
        lblTimer.Text = string.Format("Time Left: 00:0{00}:{01}",
            ((Int32)DateTime.Parse(Session["timeout"].ToString()).Subtract(DateTime.Now).TotalMinutes).ToString(),
            ((Int32)DateTime.Parse(Session["timeout"].ToString()).Subtract(DateTime.Now).Seconds).ToString());
    }
}
```

ok

Comment: It must be the delay in `Session["timeout"]`. Where do you set `Session["timeout"]`? For example if you are setting `Session["timeout"]` at another page and redirecting to this page, there will be an obvious time delay. Is that your case?

Comment: yes im redirecting to next page after time lapse... But how could it be resolved...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you are setting the `Session` variable somewhere at the start of the page, possible in `Page_Load`. After that, some time is needed to construct the page, or to execute some database statements. After that it executes the timer code and you are already some time further.

You should also know that using a `Timer`, of any sort in .NET isn't 100% reliable. The thing is that the timer suspends to the background, and the processor does some other things. After at least the interval time (so usually a little longer), the timer resumes and continues to execute. That means you will always have a delay in your code.

That means that it is possible to have miscalculations based on your timer assumptions too. Possibly the first ping-back of the timer already happened and due to the calculation rounding, you are off 2+ seconds already.

As a side note: parse your integer once, that will definitely make your code easier to read. Also, due to the repeated calculation, even the time within the statement may differ.

Answer (score 0):

In your case there could be two possible reasons for the delay.

1. Page redirection
2. Page loading

To avoid delay caused by the scenario #1 you will set the timeout session on the page where you are actually running the timer.

**Note:** You will have to set on the Page_Load and ensure that the page is not being loaded by PostBack.

So, the code block would be:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!IsPostBack)
        SetTimeout();
}

public void SetTimeout() {
    int secondsAhead = 30;
    Session["timeout"] = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(secondsAhead).ToString();
}
```

For the scenario #2 you will have to call `SetTimeout` additionally elsewhere. I would not be in a position to tell it without checking your whole page. However, this point should not trouble you if you are adding minimal controls to the page and doing somewhat minimal work on code behind too.

Try if the above fixes your issue and let me know.

Hope this helps.